# Grafana throw error after selecting more than 60 variables

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I was trying to display the metrics for 64 nodes on my k8s clsuter. Then I found out that whenever I select more than 60 nodes in the variable dropdown

[image]

Grafana throws query error that looks like this:

[image]

The exception message is not particularly helpful, could somebody provide me more insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem after selecting too many variables. As long as the rest of your monitor is able to pull the info successfully from prometheus, you can disable the annotation query. Go to the dashboard and remove the annotations under settings.